# Presentations.Open() acting weird in VSTO with Office365 version 2001

Tags: office365, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint

After updating to the latest version of Powerpoint in Office 365 (version 2001) VSTO is acting differently than before in this specific case:

- Create a new presentation
- Insert a slide from a file using the method Slides.InsertFromFile()
- Open a new presentation using the method Presentations.Open()

The result is that, after calling Presentations.Open() both the PPT passed inside Presentations.Open() and the one previously used in the method Slides.InsertFromFile() are opened as new presentations.

I've tried multiple versions of Office 365 and this is happening only in version 2001.

What I've also noticed that is different from before is that the method Slides.InsertFromFile() is actually adding a new presentation to the Presentations array.

Is there any workaround to prevent this from happening?